# Unable to resolve "./vendor/TransitionConfigs/CardStyleInterpolators" from "node_modules/react-navigation-stack/lib/module/index.js"

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo

I am getting the following error on creating the navigation stack as follows:

> Unable to resolve "./vendor/TransitionConfigs/CardStyleInterpolators" from "node_modules/react-navigation-stack/lib/module/index.js"

**App.js:-**

```
import React from "react";

import {createAppContainer,createSwitchNavigator} from "react-navigation";

import {createStackNavigator} from "react-navigation-stack";

import {createBottomTabNavigator} from "react-navigation-tabs";

import AccountScreen from "./src/screens/AccountScreen";
import SigninScreen ......  ;

const switchNavigator=createSwitchNavigator({

    loginFlow:createStackNavigator({

        Signin:SigninScreen,
        Signup:SignupScreen

    }),

    mainFlow:createBottomTabNavigator({

        trackListFlow:createStackNavigator({

            TrackList:TrackListScreen,
            TrackDetails:TrackDetailsScreen

        }),

        TrackCreate:TrackCreateScreen,
        Account:AccountScreen

    })
});

export default createAppContainer(switchNavigator);
```

I am using the following dependency version:-

**Package.json:-**

```
{

  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",

  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web",
    "eject": "expo eject"
  },

  "dependencies": {

    "expo": "~36.0.0",

    "react": "~16.9.0",

    "react-dom": "~16.9.0",

    "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-36.0.0.tar.gz",

    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.5.3",

    "react-native-reanimated": "^1.4.0",

    "react-native-web": "~0.11.7",

    "react-navigation": "^4.0.10",

    "react-navigation-stack": "^1.10.3",

    "react-navigation-tabs": "^2.7.0"

  },
  "devDependencies": {

    "babel-preset-expo": "~8.0.0",

    "@babel/core": "^7.0.0"

  },

  "private": true

}
```

While bundling I am getting the following error although I am using stable version of all the dependencies...

Answer (score 4):

You need to clear your metro Cache.

Since you're using Expo, first stop Expo server. Then run:

```sh
expo start -c
```

If you're not, run:

```sh
react-native start --reset-cache
```